# xdg-user-dirs won't update in linux applications

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xdg

I'm using Archlinux and I have two users in it. I created the first user when I was starting out with the system and this second is failry recent.

The problem is, I can't access my `xdg-user-dirs` from other applications (like inkscape's browse window) and file managers that have the `xdg-user-dirs` on the side pane, to be specific they show `/home/firstuser/Documents` instead of `/home/seconduser/Documents` it's like they aren't updated.

**But..**

When I run `$ xdg-user-dir DOCUMENTS` it displays the correct path (path for logged in or second in user).

**Here** is a list of directories in the file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

`XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"`

Thanks!

Comment: The xdg-dirs aren't supposed to need any "updating" in the first place. What are the _exact_ contents of your `user-dirs.dirs`, and what does the 2nd user's $HOME look like?

Comment: @grawity i've just updated my question to list the contents of `~/.config/xdg-user.dirs` file.
I also don't understand your second/last question. But when i `$ echo $HOME` it outputs `/home/seconduser/` correctly!

Answer (score 0):

```
# try this
xdg-user-dirs-update

# and this if you have installed xdg-user-dirs-gtk
xdg-user-dirs-gtk-update
```

Comment: I don't know why i still get the `/home/pervious-user` in these gui application (vlc, inkscape etc..)

But when i run `xdg-user-dir` i get `/home/current-user` . Can reinstalling these gui programs help?